# Non-commutative algebra (NCAlgebra): How to properly SetCommutingOperators

Tags: symbolic, packages, ncalgebra

I am starting to work with non-commutative algebra in Mathematica and had a look at the [NCAlgebra package](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/DOWNLOAD2010/DOCUMENTATION/html/NCBIGDOC.html). I installed it and can use its functions. However, what I am struggling with is the `SetCommutingOperators` command, described in I.4.6.4 of the [documentation](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/DOWNLOAD2010/DOCUMENTATION/html/NCBIGDOCch4.html#x8-770004.6). Honestly, `LeftQ`, `SetCommutingFunctions` and `SetCommutingOperators` just reference themselves in a cycle if I am not mistaken - which disallows me to fully understand the important note about using `LeftQ`.

How do I properly define that two symbols `a` and `b` commute, such that `a**b-b**a==0`. Some code with (as it appears) no effect of `SetCommutingOperators`:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`
SetCommutingOperators[a, b]
a ** b == b ** a`
(* a ** b == b ** a *)
NCE[b ** a - a ** b]
(* -a ** b + b ** a *)
```

It is important, that `a` and `b` are not commutative in general.

**Clarification**
It was suggested in a comment to use `SetCommutative[a,b]` which achieves the desired result in this case. However, this is the wrong approach as you can see if there is a second operator `c` with that `a` and `b` should not commute:

```
SetCommutative[a, b]
a**c-c**a
(* 0 *)
```

This is not desired; it should be `-c**a+a**c`. `SetCommutative` sets `a` and `b` commutative in general, but they should only commute with each other.

Comment: Why can't you just use `SetCommutative[a, b]`. It works.

Comment: @Hubble07 In some sense it does, but actually it lets `a` and `b` commute with everything. See update

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting `LeftQ[a, b] = True` together with `SetCommutingOperators` seems to work.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`

NCE[b ** a - a ** b]

(*-a ** b + b ** a`*)

SetCommutingOperators[a, b];
LeftQ[a, b] = True;

NCE[b ** a - a ** b]

(*0*)

NCE[a ** c - c ** a]

(*a ** c - c ** a*)
```

**Update providing explanation for the usage of** `SetCommutingOperators`

Firstly the [docs](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/DOWNLOAD2010/DOCUMENTATION/DOCUMENT.pdf) (see pg 74) says

> SetCommutingOperators takes exactly two parameters. SetCommutingOperators[b, c] will implement the definitions which follow ...

This means that `SetCommutingOperators` is not supposed to be used as a standalone command instead it should always be followed by setting `LeftQ`

Secondly `LeftQ` determines which of the two operators should be equated to the other.

For e.g.

```
 SetCommutingOperators[a, b];
 LeftQ[a, b] = True;

 a ** b
(*a ** b*)

 b ** a
(*a ** b*)

 SetCommutingOperators[a, b];
 LeftQ[a, b] = False;

 a ** b
(*b ** a*)

 b ** a
(*b ** a*)
```

So `LeftQ` is required to be set in order to avoid any ambiguity about which operator is actually equated to the other. This is mentioned clearly in the [**NOTE**](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/DOWNLOAD2010/DOCUMENTATION/DOCUMENT.pdf) section in that same page.

Also the order of operators in `LeftQ` should match the order in `SetCommutingOperators`. Read the [**WARNING**](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/DOWNLOAD2010/DOCUMENTATION/DOCUMENT.pdf) section in that page.

Lastly for `SetCommutingOperators` it doesn't matter if you set `LeftQ` to either `True` or `False` with the correct ordering.
I think the `True/False` matters for `SetCommutingFunctions` as seen [here](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/basiccommands.html) (scroll to the bottom).

Comment: Thanks alot! Can you explain what the `LeftQ` actually does? I'd like to understand what it is needed for

Comment: @Lukas see my updated answer

Comment: many thanks! Of course I read the description of `LeftQ` and also the referenced note. But I wasn't able to make the right out of it. Now it's clear :)

Answer (score 7):

In the newest version of [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) the command `SetCommutingOperators` has been much improved. It is implemented using UpValues for efficiency and it no longer uses `LeftQ`. Instead, it will honor whatever order you give to `SetCommutingOperators`. For example, after:

```
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`
SetCommutingOperators[a,b]
```

the following will have the results:

```
a ** b == b ** a
```

> True

```
b ** a - a ** b
```

> 0

```
a ** b
```

> a ** b

```
b ** a
```

> a ** b

If instead you use

```
SetCommutingOperators[b,a]
```

then

```
a ** b
```

> b ** a

```
b ** a
```

> b ** a